# ST_Distance is not delivering right results

Tags: postgis, distance, latitude-longitude, srid

I want to calculate the distance between lat/lon points. 
I tried the following queries:

```
Select 
ST_DISTANCE(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-73.97923 40.75571)', 4326), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-73.974509 40.757108)', 4326))
```

which gives 0.00492364143698933 as a result.

and

```
Select 
ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-73.97923 40.75571)', 4326), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-73.974509 40.757108)', 4326))
```

which gives 426.951968421872 as result.

If I look at the distance between this point in Google Maps http://goo.gl/maps/GvhFM I get 1,1 miles (~1770m) as a result. Why this mismatch? How can I get the real (Google Maps) distance?

Comment: The PostGIS distance is pretty accurate.  The correct distance between the two points specified in this question is 427.823 meters (WGS84 ellipsoid).  BTW, when the coordinates are reversed, the distance should be 528.66 meters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure those are the correct coordinates? On Google Maps, the best way to grab the coordinates is to click on the small "Maps Labs" link and enable "LatLng Marker". Then right-click on both locations, and click "drop LatLng marker".

This will show:

```
-73.9740, 40.7638
```

and

```
-73.9845, 40.7490
```

(I've rearranged to be in longitude, latitude order to make it easier).

I verified that the distance between these points is approximately 1,800m, which agrees with Google's measurement, which shows "1.8 km" (truncated to 1 decimal place).

Aside: note that a straight line on Google Maps is a loxodrome, not a geodesic, so it won't be *exactly* the same. However, at this scale, the difference will be negligible.

Comment: I didn't get the lat/lng from the URL. Used the mouse pointer..but nevertheless Select 
ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(40.75571 -73.97923)', 4326), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(40.757108 -73.974509)', 4326)) returns 526.702666151268 and  ST_DISTANCE 0.00492364143698933

Comment: I believe WKT requires POINT coordinates to be specified in the order `longitude, latitude`, so you have them the wrong way around.

Comment: This returns ST_DISTACNE: 0.00492364143698933, ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE: 426.951968421872 which is still not the result Google gives me :(

Comment: OK, I finally found the right coordinates by dropping LatLng markers, and this agrees with Google.  See edited answer.

Comment: I also tried it with the LatLng Markers (thats why I didn't look in the URL). However DISTANCE_SPHERE now returns 1868,27.. m. Which is about 100m off from the distance GoogleMaps reported.

Comment: No, Google Maps is truncating the number to one decimal place, so you need to include a margin of error. If you click "show options" and pick "km", it shows "1.8 km".

Comment: Why does the result not work with the lat/lng parameters from the URL? (see my updated query)

Comment: The URL parameters simply do not reflect the positions of the points; the URL only specifies the centre of the browser window, and the zoom level (position of one of the corners). To get the positions of the points, you need to use LatLng markers, as I mention in my answer.

Comment: Ok, this solved it. Sorry for the long discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You have your latitude and longitude reversed. POINT(40 -73) is down near the south pole, below South Africa. I'm guessing you actually want locations in the continental USA, around POINT(-73 40).

Coordinate order rule: first the X, then the Y.

Comment: Then I get 426.951968421872 as a result from DISTANCE_SPHERE, which is not the 1,8km Google reported

Comment: Great Circle Calculator also agrees with PostGIS, http://williams.best.vwh.net/gccalc.htm so maybe reconfirm how you are doing the Google calculation?